# What guarantees that there is a thermodynamic equilibrium in a closed chemical reaction network independently of the mass-action kinetics?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, kinetics

I would like to know according to which we can state that there is a unique equilibrium of a closed chemical reaction network (at constant circumstances) without supposing mass-action kinetics if time is increasing beyond all limits. Can we derive it from a non-equilibrium thermodynamic law or is it a postulate? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think what you're describing isn't a law, but a convenient way of introducing equilibrium thermodynamics. There are examples of non-equilibrium thermodynamics that are not time-invariant, such as clock reactions https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_clock

Answer (score 0):

The equilibrium is determined by the thermodynamics, not by the kinetics.  The rate constants for the reaction kinetics must be consistent with the equilibrium determined by the thermodynamics.  For example, for a single reversible reaction, the reverse reaction rate constant must be equal to the forward rate constant divided by the equilibrium constant.